# How does decimal and unitRef attributes help the numeric value to represent in XBRL

Tags: finance, xbrl

I have two financial XBRL sheet each has a different value of representation, attributes **decimal** and **unitRef** play important role to represent numeric value, but I'm facing a struggle to figure out this problem.

I have also gone through the XBRL documentation but unable to find and success, can someone help me here:

```
<ind-as:EquityShareCapital id="TAB760" decimals="-3" contextRef="I2018" unitRef="INR">325632000</ind-as:EquityShareCapital>
```

Value is shown as XBRL Validation tool

[image]

```
<in-gaap:ShareCapital contextRef="ICur" decimals="2" unitRef="Unit1">152390</in-gaap:ShareCapital>
```

And here it's shown as XBRL Validation tool

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `decimals` attribute gives you the number of decimal places that the number is accurate to.  `2` means 2 decimal places, so in the case of a number reported it dollars, it means the it is accurate to the nearest cent.  `-3` means 3 places to the left of the decimal point, or nearest thousand.  I'm not sure what you mean by "The output of numeric digit will be 3256.32".  The first value is 325,632,000 accurate to the nearest thousand.

See [XBRL 2.1 section 4.6.5](https://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html#_4.6.5).

The `unitRef` attribute is a reference to a `<unit>` element elsewhere in the report with the specified ID.  This provides the units for the fact.  A unit declaration might look something like this:

```
<xbrli:unit id="u1">
  <xbrli:measure>iso4217:EUR</xbrli:measure>
</xbrli:unit>
```

This would tell you that anything with `unitRef="u1"` is reported in EUR (Euros).

See [XBRL v2.1 section 4.8](https://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html#_4.8) and [4.6.2](https://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html#_4.6.2).

Correctly consuming XBRL documents is relatively difficult.  I would always recommend using an existing XBRL processor, such as the Open Source [Arelle](https://www.arelle.org) project as a starting point.  Processors can be used to convert to the newer [xBRL-JSON](https://specifications.xbrl.org/work-product-index-open-information-model-open-information-model.html) format, which is much easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, according to the explanation in the 1st example *325632000* value  should be represented as *325632* , but as you can see value is show different in validation tool (i.e 3256.32)

Comment: Which validation tool are you using?  Are you able to provide the complete samples that you're looking at?

Comment: Are you able to provide the complete samples that you're looking at?  From what you've posted, it looks like the tool is doing the wrong thing, but I'd need to see a sample to confirm.